# How to create sorted map in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, sortedmap

How to create sorted map in scala (mutable/immutable)?

Comment: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap exists as of 2.8, but there's no mutable version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`TreeMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.html).

Comment: Indeed.  It is immutable, so updates cost log(n) in space (i.e. garbage collector churn) as well as time.  But there isn't a mutable implementation, so it's the best solution presently (which is to say, good for most things except very intensive usage).

Answer (score 0):

There's always java.util.TreeMap which, although not as nice as Scala's maps, is probably exactly the behavior for which you're looking.